# How does "Import Flat File Wizard" work without being Bulkadmin

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I need to import files to SQL Server, but I cannot become Bulkadmin.
I can use the Import Flat File Wizard on a particular Microsoft SQL Server. But I cannot use BULK INSERT statements. I get an error: "You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement."
What SQL statements does the "Import Flat File Wizard" use to import files. It cannot be bulk insert, so how does the wizard do it.
I will add an import to a stored procedure, that is running as a job each evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Import Wizard" creates and executes an SSIS package behind the scenes.